# Error: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. with standalone component in Angular 15

Tags: angular, angular-standalone-components

I have a standalone component called home, but I am not able to have dynamic routerLinks in it even if I have imported `RouterModule` in my `[imports]` of my component. I do not have ngModules in my app to import it in app module.

This simple dynamic url was not working, what am I doing wrong?
`<a [routerLink]="url">Button</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that in standalone components you not import RouterModule, you need add as provider when you bootstrap the aplication:

```
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
]})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your `url` in the component but you can use it look like

in component:

```
url: string = './users';
```

in template:

```
<a [routerLink]="[url]">Button</a>
```

let me know if it works for you?

Comment: I get the same error still. Even I try to pass like:
`<a routerLink="/home/{{url}}">Button</a>`